# nginx, ssl_trusted_certificate and multiple certificates

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

According to the documentation, starting with nginx 1.11.0 you can specify `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` multiple times to serve RSA and ECDSA certificates for example.

However, I wasn't able to find anything related to `ssl_trusted_certificate` which is required for OCSP stapling. If the certificates from `ssl_certificate` are signed by the same CA, I don't see any problem, but what if the certificates come from different CAs?

Is `ssl_trusted_certificate` allowed multiple times as well or how do you specify multiple root CAs when serving more than one certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssl_trusted_certificate can contain multiple certificates in one file.